# How to wrap ta-lib function as a Polars expression

Tags: python, ta-lib, python-polars

I am trying to call some TA-lib(https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib) functions through Polars so that the multiple stocks' technical indicators could possibly be calculated through Polars' parallel computing framework.

Here is the sample code

```
import talib
import polars as pl
import yfinance as yf

tesla = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
tesla_data = tesla.history(period="1Y")
tesla_data["Date"]=tesla_data.index
pl_df = pl.from_pandas(tesla_data[["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]])

# Method 1. Using ta-lib as a direct function call.
mv_kama = talib.KAMA(pl_df["Close"], 30)

# Method 2. Using ta-lib as Polars expression
def kama30() -> pl.Expr:
    return talib.KAMA(pl.col("Close"), 30)

pl_df2 = pl_df.select([
    pl.col("Close"),
    kama30()
])
```

The method 2 code snippet however failed to run and the error message was:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 17>()
     14 def kama30() -> pl.Expr:
     15     return talib.KAMA(pl.col("Close"), 30)
     17 pl_df2 = pl_df.select([
     18     pl.col("Close"),
---> 19     kama30()
     20 ])

Input In [5], in kama30()
     14 def kama30() -> pl.Expr:
---> 15     return talib.KAMA(pl.col("Close"), 30)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Charm3.9\lib\site-packages\talib\__init__.py:64, in _wrapper.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwds)
     61     _args = args
     62     _kwds = kwds
---> 64 result = func(*_args, **_kwds)
     66 # check to see if we got a streaming result
     67 first_result = result[0] if isinstance(result, tuple) else result

TypeError: Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Expr)
```

Appreciate if someone could advise how this could be done properly.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no experience with polars, but I'm not sure if I'm specifying the wrong columns. I was able to get the values with the following. `return talib.KAMA(pl_df['Close'], 30)`

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I followed your suggestion and changed the Polars expression to (even though I am not quite sure we should use pl_df directly) ```def kama30() -> pl.Expr:
    return talib.KAMA(pl_df.col("Close"), 30)```, I still got the error message: ```AttributeError: col```

Answer (score 2):

To integrate TA-lib functions directly into Polars expressions, you can use the polars_talib library. Ensure you install it first by running the following command:

```
pip install polars_talib
```

After installation, you can use the library in your Python script:

```
import polars
import polars_talib as plta
import yfinance as yf

tesla = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
tesla_data = tesla.history(period="1Y")
tesla_data["Date"]=tesla_data.index
pl_df = pl.from_pandas(tesla_data[["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]])

pl_df2 = pl_df.select(
    pl.col("Close"),
    # Method 1: Using ta.kama from expr extension
    pl.col("Close").ta.kama(30).alias("KAMA"),
    
    # Method 2: Using kama from polars_talib directly
    # Note: Both methods are equivalent; you can choose the one you prefer
    plta.kama(pl.col("Close"), 30).alias("KAMA1"),
)
```

In this example, we use the ta.kama method from polars_talib to calculate the Kaufman Adaptive Moving Average with a window of 30 on the 'Close' column. You can modify the function and parameters based on your specific requirements.

For more details and a list of available TA-lib functions supported by polars_talib, refer to the github [polars_ta_extension](https://github.com/Yvictor/polars_ta_extension).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define a Polars function expression, all you need is to use the map function.  Here is the working code

```
import talib
import polars as pl
import yfinance as yf

tesla = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
tesla_data = tesla.history(period="1Y")
tesla_data["Date"]=tesla_data.index
pl_df = pl.from_pandas(tesla_data[["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]])


pl_df2 = pl_df.select([
    pl.col("Close"),
    pl.col("Close").map(lambda x: talib.KAMA(x, 30)).alias("KAMA30")
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line 15 from:

```
return talib.KAMA(pl.col("Close"), 30)
```

to:

```
return talib.KAMA(pl_df["Close"], 30)
```

To complete you can also add the columname, from:

```
pl_df2 = pl_df.select([
    pl.col("Close"),
    kama30()
])
```

to:

```
pl_df2 = pl_df.select([
    pl.col("Close"),
    pl.Series(kama30()).alias('kama30')
])
```

So the code will be:

```
import talib
import polars as pl
import yfinance as yf

tesla = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
tesla_data = tesla.history(period="1Y")
tesla_data["Date"]=tesla_data.index
pl_df = pl.from_pandas(tesla_data[["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]])

# Method 1. Using ta-lib as a direct function call.
mv_kama = pl.Series(talib.KAMA(pl_df["Close"], 30)).alias('kama30')

# Method 2. Using ta-lib as Polars expression
def kama30() -> pl.Expr:
    return talib.KAMA(pl_df["Close"], 30)

pl_df2 = pl_df.select([
    pl.col("Close"),
    pl.Series(kama30()).alias('kama30')
])

print(mv_kama)
print(pl_df2)
```

In order to keep all dataframe columns ask for pl.all() too:

```
import talib
import polars as pl
import yfinance as yf

tesla = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
tesla_data = tesla.history(period="1Y")
tesla_data["Date"]=tesla_data.index
pl_df = pl.from_pandas(tesla_data[["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]])

# Method 1. Using ta-lib as a direct function call.
# mv_kama = pl.Series(talib.KAMA(pl_df["Close"], 30)).alias('kama30')

# Method 2. Using ta-lib as Polars expression
def kama30() -> pl.Expr:
    return talib.KAMA(pl_df["Close"], 30)

pl_df2 = pl_df.select([
    pl.all(),
    # pl.col("Close"),
    pl.Series(kama30()).alias('kama30')
])

# print(mv_kama)
print(pl_df2)
```